# Cannot import pyspark in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-lambda

I want to use pyspark in my lambda function. I searched a lot on this but nothing is working. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is working"? What did you attempt? Did you consult articles like [How to Run a PySpark Application on AWS Lambda | by Amit Singh Rathore | AWS in Plain English](https://aws.plainenglish.io/spark-on-aws-lambda-c65877c0ac96) and [Serverless Spark Applications with AWS Lambda | Geek Culture](https://medium.com/geekculture/running-serverless-spark-applications-with-aws-lambda-d7e25795ec1d)? Please tell us more.

Comment: I tried the second one but I cannot import sagemaker in lambda function. I am trying the docker one now.